# PHP Form Checking For Text and Image

Tags: php, forms

I have a question on PHP form checking for posting text and image. How do i handle form checking for both type of data?

```
$latErr = $lngErr = $photoErr = "";
$lat = $lng = $photo = "";

//what if i am not using form action-PHP_SELF, currently i am use anotherfile.php, what do i use below?
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["inputfield1"])) {
 $latErr = "Latitude is required. Enable your browser geolocation.";
} else {
 $lat = test_input($_POST["inputfield1"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["inputfield2"])) {
 $lngErr = "Longitude is required. Enable your browser geolocation.";
} else {
 $lng = test_input($_POST["inputfield2"]);
}

//can i check for image like this?
if (empty($_POST["photo"])) {
 $photoErr = "Please select your image.";
} else {
 $photoErr = test_input($_POST["photo"]);
}
}
```

Comment: what if i am not using form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" I use form action="addfile.php"

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the input type `file`, then check if `$_FILES` has any uploaded images:

```
if (empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])) {
    // error - no photo selected
}
if (empty($_POST['inputfield1'])) {
    // error - no text input
}


// ...
// ... form ...
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photo" />
    <input type="text" name="inputfield1" />
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses cURL without sending an image, your code will crash because it's trying to see if there's something called "photo" sent via POST. You should try doing something like this:

```
if( $_FILES['photo']['error'] == 4 )
 $photoErr = "No file was uploaded";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_FILES['input_field_name']['name'])){
    //File Exists
}

if(isset($_POST['input_fiel_text'])){
    //Text field exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get more information about images for a good control

```
        $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
        $dir = pathinfo($name);
        $extension = $dir['extension'];
        $extensionsAutorisees = array("png","gif","bmb");
        $to_dir = dirname(__FILE__)."/img/";
        $new_name = $name.".".$extension;

        if (!(in_array($extension, $extensionsAutorisees))) {
             .... error with extension alow
        } else {    
             ..... your action
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Mark M's answer, he is right, but I would like to add the validation of your uploaded images to that:

```
public static function isValidUpload() {

    if ($_FILES['photo']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        return false;
    }

    $info = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);

    return !(($info === FALSE) || (($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_GIF) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_JPEG) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_PNG)));
}
```

Do not check the extension, as I can write a PHP file and save it as evil.png. In that case, despite the fact that the extension is png, it would be a potentially dangerous php.